# Fetching https content via api on client site but browsers raising mixed content http errors

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api, mixed-content

I'm trying to build an external API in a Django app to serve some content over to a production client Wordpress site. The client is on https and the javascript uses fetch to get https api url but browsers are claiming http mixed content.  What gives?

I've tried both Chrome and Firefox and both are returning similar errors

```
fetch('https://mysite.pythonanywhere.com/apit?param1=100000&param2=1000', {
    method: 'GET',
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
        response.status);
      return;
    }
  });
```

my view for this in Django has:

```
response = JsonResponse(the_content_dict,safe=False)
return response
```

I can visit the URL directly in my browser and view the json response as expected but when I place the code above on the client WP site, I see in the Firefox console:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mysite.pythonanywhere.com/apit?param1=100000&param2=1000”

TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. rank:154:3
Response { type: "cors", url: "https://mysite.pythonanywhere.com/apit?param1=100000&param2=1000", redirected: false, status: 500, ok: false, statusText: "Internal Server Error", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: 500
```

Similarly, in Chrome:

```
(index):154 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://clientsite.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://mysite.pythonanywhere.com/apit?param1=100000&param2=1000'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(anonymous) @ (index):154
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Why are the browsers trying to load the non https version instead of the https in the fetch?  I'm using django-cors-headers to whitelist the client domain which appears to be working.

Comment: Do you have some type of redirect in your code, redirecting it to an insecure resource. This is clearly not a CORS issue: It has to do with accessing http vs https

Comment: Incidentally, seems like you have a bigger problem than just the mixed-content issue: the console message shows that the response is a 500 Internal Server Error…